# STW-cocoa library missing in win8 64bit

Tags: java, cocoa, swt

I developed a program on MAC. Program uses SWT library.
i want to run it on win8 64bit. I suppose i have to change some libraries, but can't figure it out...
My manifest has these imports:

`swt.jar swing2swt.jar`
`RXTXcomm.jar`
`org.csstudio.swt.widgets_2.1.0.201209121549.jar` `org.csstudio.swt.widgets.source_2.1.0.201209121549.jar` `org.csstudio.swt.xygraph_2.1.0.201209121540.jar` `org.csstudio.swt.xygraph.source_2.1.0.201209121540.jar` `org.eclipse.draw2d_3.9.0.201308190730.jar` 
`org.eclipse.jface_3.9.1.v20130725-1141.jar` `org.eclipse.core.commands_3.6.100.v20130515-1857.jar` `org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.200.v20130402-1505.jar`
`org.eclipse.osgi_3.9.1.v20140110-1610.jar`

all these jar's are in the same folder with my program jar.
so far on windows I get an exception: 
`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError, Could not load SWT library. Reasons: no swt-cocoa-4333 in java.library.path, no swt-cocoa in java.library.path.`

isn't cocoa is part of MAC OS X?

what do i miss?

Answer (score 0):

well, no need to answer, i just figured it out.
some SWT imports was missing and i had to change swt.jar.